# extracting lines in a text file between two lines of strings

Tags: python

I have the following example text file (it is in the format as indicated below). I want to extract everything between the lines "Generating configuration...." and "`show accounting log all`", this is the beginning and end of what I am interested in.

some lines 
some more line 
Generating configuration.... 
interested config 
interested config 
interested config 
`show accounting log all` 
some lines 
some more line

I wrote the following code, but its does not stop appending the lines to the textfile after it has found `show accounting log all`.

```
    config_found = False
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        textfile_temp = f.readlines()

    for line in textfile_temp:
        if re.match("Generating configuration....", line):
            config_found = True
        if re.match("`show accounting log all`", line):
            config_found = False
        if config_found:
            i = line.rstrip()
            textfile.append(i)
```

what am i doing wrong with my statements?

Comment: Looks like in your example content they are backticks around `show accounting log all` and in your code it's looking for single quotes, so it will never match. (Why are you using the regex module re, instead of plain string comparison?)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of single quotes, you have to use back quote in your comparision and you can have if and elif for extracting in between strings. I have modified as below and it's working:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    textfile_temp = f.readlines()
    config_found = False
    textfile = []
    for line in textfile_temp:
        if re.match("`show accounting log all`", line):
            config_found = False
        elif config_found:
            i = line.rstrip()
            textfile.append(i)
        elif re.match("Generating configuration....", line):
            config_found = True
    print textfile
```

Output:

```
  ['interested config', 'interested config', 'interested config']
```

Instead you can use split as below:

```
 with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()
     print textfile_temp.split('Generating configuration....')[1].split("`show accounting log all`")[0]
```

Output:

```
interested config 
interested config 
interested config
```

Comment: Just to add on, the "backtick" character can be found on the keyboard usually just above the "tab" key, on the same key as "tilde" (~) key.

Comment: user3 thanks this worked! What was wrong with the if statements I had in my original code (I had fixed the backticks and it still failed)? I can't seem to understand why it wouldnt have worked.

Comment: you are loading the result variable after that you are changing config_found variable. that should be reversed.

Answer (score 0):

`config_found` appears to have no scope *outside* of the loop.

Put `config_found = False` before the loop and it should work fine.